# Possible to get SMS/text message notification when process ends or is killed?

Tags: shell, process, email, monitoring, sms

There are scripts that will send an e-mail when a server process is finished.

However, I do not want to check my email every so often just to see whether a job has finished. Therefore I'd like to get an SMS message.

My question is similar to this one, just exchange SMS with all occurrences of "e-mail": [Is there a program that can send me a notification e-mail when a process finishes?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/55395/is-there-a-program-that-can-send-me-a-notification-e-mail-when-a-process-finishe)

Can you think of any workaround / app / script / whatever that would enable an SMS to be sent when a job is finished (or prematurely ended?)

Comment: http://serverfault.com/search?q=SMS+notification

Comment: Today, IFTTT would be another option.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There are 3 ways to accomplish the sending of an SMS message from a server  and/or application.

1. Setup your own gateway

   If you google for "sms gateway" you'll find a large list of applications that you can setup which will provide this capability. You can also take an old cell phone and a PC and set them up using this tutorial titled: [Setting up an SMS Gateway](http://www.x11.net/wiki/index.php/Setting_up_an_SMS_Gateway) to create your own SMS gateway.
2. Use a ready made service

   There are service providers that offer this capability (typically for a fee). Here are a couple of them:

   *fee*

   - http://www.esendex.co.uk/
   - http://www.twilio.com/

   *free*

   - http://www.kannel.org/

   These providers often provide a library and/or API, [such as this one from twilio](http://www.twilio.com/docs/libraries), so that you can integrate them more easily into your application if needed.
3. Send an email to your provider's [SMS gateway](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SMS_gateway)

   Most providers (Verizon, AT&T, etc.) provide the ability to send an SMS message to your phone using the `<phonenumber>@provider.com`. [Wikipedia also has a pretty exhaustive list of SMS gateways](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_SMS_gateways).

Comment: Accepting this even though it does not provide a cut and paste answer since it seems to be a moderately involved process. Thanks, btw.

Comment: @TheUnfunCat - yes there are a lot of choices so it'd be difficult to give you just a single solution.

Answer (score 4):

Another option if you have an android phone: use [NotifyMyAndroid](https://www.notifymyandroid.com/) to send push messages to your phone.

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at [gcsms](https://github.com/oxplot/gcsms) if you have a Google account. It's sort of a hack that uses Google's calendar event notification to send free SMS to your phone right from the shell. You can even send SMS to multiple people provided they've set up their settings properly.

By the way, I am the creator of gcsms.

Comment: Google is discontinuing the SMS notifications

Comment: @dbza but only for free gmail accounts. If you have Google for Work account, it'll continue to work.

Comment: cool I didn't know that

Answer (score 1):

```
#!/bin/bash
# this will send an sms message
# usage: script.name "message you want to send"

echo -e "ATZ\r" >/dev/ttyACM0
echo -e "AT+CMGF=1\r" >/dev/ttyACM0
echo -e "AT+CMGS=\"1234567890\"\r" >/dev/ttyACM0 
echo -e "$1\x1A" >/dev/ttyACM0
```

Answer (score 0):

I also wanted something for notifying me after training ML models has completed and made a free light service for this purpose.

https://getvigil.io

Just set up your email or phone number, download the binary for your platform, write the config file with your creds and run:

```
vigil echo "hello world"
```

Also plan to expand to push notifications and watching command output/notifying based on match rules.

Answer (score 0):

I run into this issue a lot, not only with shell commands but anywhere else I need a notification when some process finishes. I found this site that gives you a URL, that when hit, sends you a text message. So you can run your command as such
`<some command> && curl <url>` and you'll get a text when it finishes. Its at https://www.comunicake.com